# Selenium webdriver does not open the most recent iteration of webpage?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I trying to make a selenium script that checks a real estate website and emails any new properties.  all of the old properties are stored in a databases, the listings are cross checked against the database and new ones are emailed.

I got it working pretty well, however I noticed that if I myself navigate to said real estate website manually I see 3-4 new listings.  When I run the script through task manager and the driver opens the page through firefox, the driver does not see those newly listed properties! Why is this happening? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your browser is caching the outdated information.

Try calling:

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

After instantiating your driver, and before navigating to your page.